# How to put different separators between columns in a file in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, tex

I have a huge data file in which there is space between columns as a separator.
I wan to put tab between every other 2 coloumn and the need to be 2 space between each pair of columns. As a small example to clarify what I mean:

input file:

```
   1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 

   1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 

   1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2
```

I want the output file be like:

```
1  1    1  1    2  1    2  2    2  1    1  1    2  2    1  2
1  1    1  1    1  1    2  2    1  1    1  1    2  2    2  2
1  1    1  1    1  1    2  2    1  1    1  1    2  2    2  2
```

Any suggestion please? Note that the real file has more than 50,000 columns and rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) printf "%s  %s%s", $(i-1), $i, (i<NF ? "\t" : ORS)}' file
1  1    1  1    2  1    2  2    2  1    1  1    2  2    1  2
1  1    1  1    1  1    2  2    1  1    1  1    2  2    2  2
1  1    1  1    1  1    2  2    1  1    1  1    2  2    2  2
```

Answer (score 2):

another `awk`

```
$ awk -v OFS="  " '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2)$i=$i" "}1' file
```

Comment: Ok, another `awk` is a good bit of smart thinking to avoid the division/mod overhead with a step size of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Something like `cat file.name | perl -pe 's/([^ ]+ [^ ]+) /\1   /g'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awk:

```
awk '{printf "%s", $1;
      for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s", (i%2 ? "   " : "  ") $i; print ""}' file

1  1   1  1   2  1   2  2   2  1   1  1   2  2   1  2
1  1   1  1   1  1   2  2   1  1   1  1   2  2   2  2
1  1   1  1   1  1   2  2   1  1   1  1   2  2   2  2
```

Answer (score 0):

You would like a simple `sed` command like

```
echo "1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 2" |
   sed 's/ \([^ ]\) /  \1   /g'
```

This one has a little bug that is difficult to see with the spaces. I will use a x first:

```
echo "1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 2" |
   sed 's/ \([^ ]\) /xx\1xxx/g'
# Result:
1xx1xxx1xx1xxx2xx1xxx2xx2xxx2xx1xxx1xx1xxx2xx2xxx1 2
```

Wow! When you have an even number of fields the last separator is skipped. You can patch it (now I will use a `y` for marking the patch).

```
echo "1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 2" | 
   sed 's/ \([^ ]\) /xx\1xxx/g; s/\([^ ]\) \([^ ]*\)$/\1yy\2/'
# Result
1xx1xxx1xx1xxx2xx1xxx2xx2xxx2xx1xxx1xx1xxx2xx2xxx1yy2
```

Now replace  the temp `x` and `y` with spaces:

```
echo "1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 2" |
   sed 's/ \([^ ]\) /  \1   /g; s/\([^ ]\) \([^ ]*\)$/\1  \2/'
```